# How to measure execution time of each processor in Nifi

Tags: logging, time, apache-nifi

I need the time when onTrigger method from each processor from my flow is entered and also exited.

Given that I have 7 processors, I need also the time when onTrigger from first processor in flow is entered and onTrigger from last processor in flow is exited (or any other 3 linked processors from this flow).

I also need this to be turned on/off from UI.

Comment: You `need` a lot of things! Can you please show us what you have done so far to accomplish the same?  Do you have any thoughts on how this can be implemented? What processors/attributes can be used etc? Without showing your own effort to solve the problem, it would be really difficult to get help.

Comment: Most of the processors in my flow are custom and I was thinking on creating a custom reporting task to capture the time values I need but at a first glance that seems an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing AspectJ and it works wonderfully. In all processors, I added a property that had 2 values(enable and disable) that I read in the aspect class to satisfy the "turning it on/off from UI" part of the task.